# Why XMonad run child processes in new session?

Tags: session, haskell, launcher, xmonad

I have some questions about XMonad run program procedure. Answers to these questions also, I hope, explain “canonical” way to run applications in X environment.

XMonad uses function '[spawn](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/src/XMonad-Core.html#spawn)' to run terminal emulator and program launcher (e. g. gmrun).

This function call 'spawnPID', which construct '/bin/sh cmd' command.

**Question 1:** why we need to execute '/bin/sh -c cmd', not simply 'cmd'?

My supposition: for parsing arguments, which can be added to command in xmonad.hs.

Further. For execute constructed command 'spawnPID' called 'xfork' function, which:

- fork process (possibly to prevent process being group leader, required by setsid syscall);
- restore default SIGPIPE and SIGCHLD (looks like forkProcess behaviour workaround);
- call 'createSession' (setsid syscall wrapper);
- execute command constructed in 'spawnPID'.

**Questions 2 (main):** why XMonad execute each child process in it’s own session?

In my opinion, session mainly associated with user login session or “users independently” programs, i. e. daemons. Not with each separate program under one login session.

**Question 3:** why forkProcess+executeFile even used, not shell+createProcess or proc+createProcess?

'forkProcess' seems to partly deprecated (under multiprocessor systems in some cases, see [this](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/libraries/unix-2.4.2.0/System-Posix-Process.html)), but 'createProcess' must work fine in this case and support executing under shell without typing '/bin/sh -c'.

This is maybe better way to deal with executing program. But I’m not professional in that, only briefly read documentation.

Comment: I think using `/bin/sh` is probably just so that you can pass a command name and `sh` searches for it in the `PATH`.

Comment: 'executeFile' function can perform search executables in PATH directories itself.

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderTurenko; I believe the reason for `sh -c` is to get shell-parsing of the command -- e.g. expand globs, allow chaining, allow variable interpolation, etc. No idea about the motivation for the session and forking shenanigans, though.